# FQL fetch 3 photos from each album

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is there an “elegant way” to fetch last 3 photos from each album of user? I’ve tried using this multiquery, but it doesn’t work:

```
  $fqls = array(
    "q1" => "SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = $page_id",
    "q2" => "SELECT src_small,created FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM #q1) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 3"
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with graph api, you can do something like `[user_id]/albums?fields=photos.limit(3)`